# jQuery tabs not working in production environment

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have some jQuery tabs running in a basic html page:

http://mrttabtest.azurewebsites.net/tabtest.html

Everything works as intended, & the tabs flick from one lot of content to the other as expected.

However, when I put this into my real world environment, I hit a snag with the console returning `TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function`

http://mrttabtest.azurewebsites.net/realtabtest.html

Aside from the addition of angular.js (I've tried turning it off), & the aside tag for the menu items(I've tried adding the tag div both inside & outside of this) I'm a bit lost in the woods.  Whats going on?!!

I'm trying to use the left hand menu to select different tabbed pages using the jQuery tabs function.  I've purchased the theme (Altair on CodeCanyon)...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**

Comment: Try to remove all your JS files except Jquery and Jquery UI and see if it is working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though UIKit and the Altair menu scripts are the culprits. As soon as I remove them, the code listed here works in the console:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

What's also weird is that doing `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();` alone doesn't work in this scenario. It seems though that conflicting JS may be it. It's also good to note that jQuery UI is very bulky and finding an alternative is a good choice for site performance.

Some alternatives are listed here:

1. http://peteschuster.com/2012/01/replacing-jquery-ui-tabs/
2. http://www.slidetabs.com/
3. Angular.JS Tabs: https://thinkster.io/angular-tabs-directive

Comment: I was just discovering that from Suraj' comments.  I'm probably getting a little out of my depth.  Any suggestions as to a suitable fix or alternative method?

Comment: What's funny is that after I remove those two scripts the code here still doesn't work until I add `$(document).ready();`: `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();` Maybe the DOM hasn't loaded?

Comment: Presumably it needs to wait for the page to fully load?

Comment: @MrT That's what I presumed, but usually it'll work dynamically after the page has loaded. Weird.

Comment: I'm looking further.  Here is the original html theme: http://themeforest.net/item/altair-material-design-premium-template/full_screen_preview/12190654

Comment: Looks like I'm trying to do something that its not designed to do & there is obviously something going on (probably in altair) that is getting in the way of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: That's what it sounded like. I'm looking into it too, to see if there's a workaround instead of using `$.tabs();`

Comment: Another thing to note is that jQuery UI is very bulky, and using an alternative will make your site run faster.

Comment: I'm looking through the theme again.  They provide a php html version & an angular.js version.  I might have a play around with them & see which one works the best.  No point in reinventing the wheel!  I purchased the theme for speed & competency reasons...

Comment: Well you could use a jQuery plugin like this: http://jellekralt.github.io/Responsive-Tabs/#tab-2
It may work even with the current scenario.

Comment: Feels a bit like cheating... I'm going to try & look for a native solution (or forget tabs) in the theme.  I've ended up down this route as a method to easily maintain menus, etc.  Perhaps the Angular option will do the trick (just need to learn angular!!!).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Clarified my thoughts! :)

Comment: I'm not very good with Angular, didn't even know it had menus. You're very welcome. I'll try to include the gist of our discussion in the answer, and if you could, can you please accept it?

Comment: Done... Might find these of interest re- Angular: https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/single-page-applications-with-jquery-or-angularjs-8414 & https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/introduction-to-angularjs-8682?l=qJ8KNLH1_1804984382

Comment: Check the edited post. Found an alternative to jQuery UI using Angular.JS tabs.